# Can I create an auto-complete dropdown text-box in angular with little amount of code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement an auto-complete drop-down input-box using angularJs. And yes, there are plenty of solutions out there in both angular and jquery. But the problem is that they seem unnecessarily complicated for what I need. So far I have most of the logic developed by very limited code in angular and what it lacks is a decent appearance for a drop-down input-box.

I have this simple directive:

```
app.directive('autoCompleteBox', function() {
    return { restrict: 'E', 
    templateUrl: '/pathTo/auto-complete-inputbox.html',
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.items=JSON.parse(attrs.items);
    }
};
```

});

And the template is as following - just a very simple text-box and a list that when I write in the text-box I can filter through them using very simple filter code in angular:

```
<div>
    <input type='text' ng-model='test'>
        <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter:test track by $index '> 
            {{item}}       
        </li>
    </input>
</div>
```

And when I want to use the directive I use:

```
<auto-complete-box items="[myArray]"> </auto-complete-box>
```

And here is an image of what I get as a result of this code.

[image: here]

Any ideas how can I have a simple and clean editable drop-down box (without arrow) added on top of this code to make it an auto-complete drop-down box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be help u https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/autocomplete/js/autocompleteDirective.js

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836719/suggetion-in-text-box-possible

Answer (score 1):

use the angular js ng-autocomplete module to simple directive for adding to dropdown text-box.

see the [demo](http://goo.gl/yvhvym)

Comment: Not a simple one. But still cleaner than others. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use material design for implementing Autocomplete and various other components. Material design components is a good thing to use with AngularJs.
Hope this will help to you.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried material design, but as I said it was to much more than what I need and consequently it has got very long code for functionalities that I don't need.

Comment: I don't know what is your requirement but md-autocomplete is good solution.

Comment: Have you heard about Wijmo library but it is paid.