# Suggestion in text box possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a input box with type text:

```
<input type="text></input>
```

I have a list of names:

```
 $scope.employees = [{
    name: "vishnu"
 }, {
    name: "seenu"
 }];
```

Now let it be only 2.
When I type `v`, it should show `vishnu` as suggestion. When I type `se, it should show`seenu` as suggestion. How can this be achieved?

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590468/angularjs-form-input-suggestions

Comment: ngAutoComplete : `http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

Comment: mmmm...possible... better chat with me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Populate options of [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) with values in `$scope.employees` with [data-ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.employees = [{
      name: "vishnu"
    },
    {
      name: "seenu"
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" list="names" placeholder="Pick a name..">
  <datalist id="names">
    <option  data-ng-repeat="item in employees" value="{{item.name}}">
  </datalist>  
</div>
```

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 0):

There is simple example given below with Jquery autocomplete

```
$scope.complete=function(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5XmPfQ78vRjSrxE0Tt3B?p=preview

Comment: this will work but its nice if it will behave as an autocomplete :) like hovering results

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.employees = [{
      name: "vishnu"
    },
    {
      name: "seenu"
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" list="names" placeholder="Pick a name..">
  <datalist id="names">
    <option  data-ng-repeat="item in employees" value="{{item.name}}">
  </datalist>  
</div>
```