# get object from datalist ng-repeat angular

Tags: angularjs, datalist

I got datalist such as below ,and color a color object with name and id properties.

```
<datalist id="opts">
<option ng-repeat="color in colors" value = "{{color.id}}">color.name</option>
</datalist>
```

My problem is that i want to run a function with the id and the name of the selected color. how can i access both of them without show the id on the view?

```
<button ng-click="someFunction(color.id,color.name)">button </button>
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836719/suggestion-in-text-box-possible

Answer (score 2):

You should do it manually, as `ng-options` directive would be good option to go, but unfortunately it doesn't supported for `datalist`. To get selected value inside controller scope you need to add `ng-model` to `datalist`

**Markup**

```
<datalist id="opts" ng-model="selectedColor">
   <option ng-repeat="color in colors" value = "{{color.id}}">color.name</option>
</datalist>

<button ng-click="someFunction(selectedColor)">button</button>
```

And then do filter on color collection inside controller `someFunction`

```
$scope.someFunction = function(){
    var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.colors, {id: parseInt(selectedColor)}, true),
        selectedColor;
    if(selected){
       selectedColor = selected[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I try and selectedColor is still undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

Use **Angular Expression** to Bind `{{color.name}}` in option or use Value attribute

```
<option ng-repeat="color in colors" value = "{{color.id}}" ng-change="someFunction(color )">{{color.name}}</option>
```

You can also give a try to use

```
ng-change
```

in side the datalist
Example:

```
<datalist id="opts">
<option ng-repeat="color in colors" value = "{{color.id}}" ng-change="someFunction(color )">{{color.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Now With in the Function You can Access both the id and name...For this No need of `submit button`

```
 $scope.someFunction = function(colorobj){
       var colorid=colorobj.id;
       var colorname=colorobj.name;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do as illustrated below.

Pass directly the object - 'color' and access the 'id', 'name', etc in the controller.

HTML:

```
  <button ng-click="someFunction(color)">button </button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.someFunction = function (colorObj) {
      // access colorObj.id, colorObj.name, etc.
}
```

Comment: you can't pass `color` object, as it is not selected `datalist`

Comment: it could be if he changed the value from color.id to color